# I have three different websites and I want to create a single entry point for all of them but how?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, cookies, user-accounts

We are creating three different websites using asp.net but for the user part we want to implement an approach so that each user only need to create an account in any of these three sites but use the same account in other websites too.
here is what I've suggested :

create a 
useracount.website.com server
then  put the sql server there and implement core user account library there such as (creating/editing/etc...)

whenever a visitor needs to have an account or needs to login into out sites then we will redirect him to the useracount.website.com address and he/she should login from that point.
and for the maintaining the user's states I've suggested to using cookies.

and all of these scenarios should be implemented by asp.net and sql.

please let me know with best approach cause I feel mine is not that good specially the cookie part.

cheers.

Comment: Are your three sites hosted on the same server?

Comment: The design you are referring to is "single sign-on", a form of access control where a single "sign-on" system exists that provides access control to multiple other systems. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for *`Single Sign-on in Web Farms`*

Here is an [Introduction](http://aspalliance.com/1545_understanding_single_signon_in_aspnet_20.all)